# How does the MSSM pseudo-scalar heavy Higgs undergo the decay process A -> Z h?

Tags: mssm

As A is a pseudo-scalar, Z an axial vector and h being a scalar, it looks like the spins are not balanced on both sides. Is it related to the longitudinal mode of Z boson?

Comment: So your not using A as it usually stands for as EM gauge field? What are you using it as?

Comment: No. The A here doesn't stand for the EM gauge field. The A here refers to the pseudo-scalar Higgs boson in MSSM.